# How to type a React component that accepts its child props as their own?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a component that has the same behavior as `React.cloneElement`, but with some safeguards, but I'm having trouble coming up with the types.

The API I want would be something like this (similar to Radix's `asChild` prop as if they were always on):

```
<Slot onClick={() => {}}>
  <button type="button">Click me</button>
</Slot>
```

The problem is that the component is not validating whether its props are usable by its child. What I was hoping is that when something like this was provided, it would warn me somehow:

```
// no warns displayed
<Slot customProp="pudding">
  <button type="button">Click me</button>
</Slot>
```

The component code is the following:

```
function Slot<ChildProps>({
  children: child,
  ...restProps
}: { children: ReactElement<ChildProps> } & Partial<Omit<ChildProps, 'children'>>) {
  if (Children.count(child) > 1) {
    throw new Error('Only one child allowed');
  }

  if (!isValidElement(child)) {
    return null;
  }

  return cloneElement(child, {
    ...restProps,
    ...child.props,
  });
}
```

Is there any way to make this type work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi you can use state lifting or use global state with ridux toolkit

Answer (score 0):

To enforce type safety and ensure that only valid props are passed to the child component, you can create a TypeScript-friendly component with better type checking. To achieve this, you can use TypeScript generics along with React's ReactElement type to define the slot component.

**Here's an example implementation:**

```
   import React, { isValidElement, ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react';

type SlotProps<ChildProps extends Record<string, any>> = {
  children: ReactElement<ChildProps>;
} & Partial<Omit<ChildProps, 'children'>>;

function Slot<ChildProps extends Record<string, any>>({
  children: child,
  ...restProps
}: SlotProps<ChildProps>) {
  if (React.Children.count(child) > 1) {
    throw new Error('Only one child allowed');
  }

  if (!isValidElement(child)) {
    return null;
  }

  const childProps = child.props as ChildProps;

  // Filter out props that are not present in the child component's props
  const filteredProps: Partial<ChildProps> = Object.keys(restProps).reduce(
    (acc, key) => {
      if (key in childProps) {
        acc[key as keyof ChildProps] = restProps[key as keyof ChildProps];
      } else {
        console.warn(`Warning: Prop '${key}' is not valid for the child component`);
      }
      return acc;
    },
    {}
  );

  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    ...childProps,
    ...filteredProps,
  });
}

// Usage example:
type ButtonProps = {
  onClick: () => void;
  type?: 'button' | 'submit' | 'reset';
  children: ReactNode;
};

function ExampleComponent() {
  return (
    <Slot<ButtonProps> onClick={() => console.log('Clicked')}>
      <button type="button">Click me</button>
    </Slot>
  );
}

export default ExampleComponent;
```

Slot is a generic component that takes ChildProps, which represents the props expected by the child component.
The Slot component checks the number of children and validates if there's only one child.
It then filters the props passed to the Slot component to only pass valid props that exist in the child component.
If a prop is provided that doesn't exist in the child component, it logs a warning.
Finally, it clones the child element with the filtered props merged with the original child props using React.cloneElement.
This way, you'll get type safety and warnings when invalid props are passed to the Slot component that the child component doesn't support. Adjust the ButtonProps type to match the expected props of your actual child component.